# Как убрать анонимность функции?

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, после переноса сайта на сервер с php 4.2 стала вылезать ошибка в синтаксисе: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'

Понял, что это из-за анонимной функции, но как правильно переписать код не получается.

Сейчас так:

```
        $dataAttributes = array_map(function($value, $key) {
        return $key . "='" . (str_replace("'", '"', $value)) . "'";
    }, array_values($attributes), array_keys($attributes));
```

Comment: как вариант, один с лучших, не использовать сервер  с php 4.2, а второй, перепиши все на foreach

Comment: Бегите с этого сервера, если там действительно стоит php версии 4.2.

Comment: @Visman может кто-то любит пожёстче)

Comment: Насколько же старый у тебя клиент локалхоста. У тебя наверное еще `HTTP_SERVER_VARS` вместо `$_SERVER`

Comment: Парни, все это понимаю, но новичок в кодинге пока.. Кто сможет конкретно подсказать по коду?

Comment: поименовать ее! :)

Answer (score 1):

Несколько странно начинать изучать программирование с достаточно древних версий php. Данной версии, уже, кажется, больше 15 лет. В 2004м году уже вышел пхп 5, а 4й версия появилась в 2000-м. Но в целом, если вы пользуетесь `win98` и `Internet Explorer 6`, то `PHP4` отлично дополнит эту компанию.

Для решения конкретно вашего вопроса, можете либо переписать задачу с использованием простого цикла `foreach`, либо по-старинке передать в `array_map` имя функции, вместо реализации:

```
function map($value, $key){
    return $key . "='" . (str_replace("'", '"', $value)) . "'";
}

$test = array_map("map", array_values($attributes), array_keys($attributes))
```

То есть из анонимной функции мы сделали именованную.

Второй же вариант, который, наверное, будет проще, и даже уместнее - обычный цикл по массиву:

```
$test2 = array();
foreach($attributes as $k=>$value){
    $test2[] = $k."=".(str_replace("'", '"', $value)) . "'";
}
```

Comment: А разве IE 6 на Win 98? Вроде на XP же?

Comment: XP же - оговорка по Фрейду :D